# print `object_list` within ListView

Tags: django

I have the following class in `views.py`:

```
class RestaurantListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = RestaurantLocation.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)
        return  qs
```

in `restaurantlocation_list.html`

```
<ul>
        {% for obj in object_list  %}
            <li>obj</li>
        {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I want to print `object_list` within `views.py` by adding `print` statement,

```
class RestaurantListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = RestaurantLocation.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)
```

Add print statement:

```
    print(object_list)
    return  qs
```

Error reports then:

```
NameError: name 'object_list' is not defined
```

What confuses me is that `template` receive arguments from views, whereas it can not be reached in views?
How to print the `object_list` in views.py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the view the context variables for the HTML Template are stored in a dictionary. In your CBV you should access it by `self.object_list`.

Make sure you call it after `get_context_data()` is called. Even better, if you want to dump the data just for debugging, overwrite get_context_data() and print it out there.

https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.views.generic.list/ListView/

Comment: change to `print(self.context['object_list'])`, reports `'RestaurantListView' object has no attribute 'context'`

Comment: modified my answer